# Change record position internally

Tags: delphi, firebird

I use disablecontrols method for master/detail tables and I am looking for a way to change the record position internally (while within disable controls) in the component level (IBDAC) without using bookmarks or locate

Thanks

Comment: How do you know what record to change to? How would you identify it?

Comment: if there is an internal way to change position it should also have a way to get a certain position.

Answer (score 0):

Try [RecNo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSet.RecNo) and check out [Navigating Data in Client Datasets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Navigating_Data_in_Client_Datasets)

Apart from that, I think this is probably a design issue you need to address, but I'm not sure. I normally fetch all the data I need, then a single unidirectional pass through the dataset is usually enough. If necessary, make a second pass (rarely), but I've never had to move back and forth several times within a dataset. There is probably a better way. Hope that helps.